# django-rest-framework using views returns 500 with a POST

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to get the following to work: http://django-rest-framework.org/examples/views.html in my own django app. When I do a GET it returns 200 and provides the correct response. However, when I attempt a POST all I get is a 500 error. I am completely stumped, it seems so simple I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

***urls.py:***

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
from test.testapp.views import ws_list

urlpatterns = patterns('test.testapp.views',
    ...
    url(r'^ws/List/$', ws_list.as_view()),
    url(r'^ws/List/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ws_list.as_view()),
)
```

***views.py:***

```
...
from djangorestframework.views import View

class ws_list(View):

    def get(self, request, pk=0):
        if pk == 0:
            rtStr = 'GET the whole list'
        else:
            rtStr ="GET request to List %s" % pk
        return rtStr

    def post(self, request, pk=0):
        return "POST request to List %s, with content: %s" % (pk, repr(self.CONTENT))
```

I've also tried adding in the forms.py for validation but, like I suspected, it didn't do anything. It seems that this should be so easy, I just can't understand why it wont work...

Comment: Are you running the Django development server and/or have `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py`? The highly informative stacktrace provided solves about 90%+ of these problems.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I had set it to False a while ago and had forgotten...it helps the have the / at the end of your url :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to add the trialing / to the web service call...turning on debugging helps!